# Regular expression that does not contain a word KT in nth and n+1 positions

Tags: java, regex

I have a regular expression that a substring is not contained in 3nd and 4th positions together. the below is such expression.

```
[a-z][K][^K][^T][B][T][A-Z][0-9][a-z]
```

total letters: 9,
3rd and 4th position should not be KT. but it is also not accpeting AT,KA as well.i want AT,KA is to be accepted.

there is one more expression below where it has to accept KKTBT from 2nd position to 6 th positions and 1st position should be only letter and 7th positions should be only capital letters, and 8th postion should be only number and 9 th position should be only small letters.

I have written below for pattern matching. is this correct.? or do we have better way than below.

```
[a-z][K][K][T][B][T][A-Z][0-9][a-z]
```

Comment: Note that `[K][K][T][B][T]` is the same as `KKTBT`.

Comment: [a-z]KKTBT[A-Z][0-9][a-z] will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to mean `([^K].|.[^T])` instead of `[^K][^T]` which specifically says only match if non-K is followed by non-T.

What exactly works also depends on which regular expression engine you are using; please review the [`regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) for further guidance.

Demo: https://ideone.com/DYOhBO

... though as noted in comments, `[K]` can be simplified to `K`, etc.